# Comments Template shows, but not the comments

Tags: comments

I've customized a twentytwelve theme, changed the index and content, nothing else. Now, I've lost the comments.

Google says to call this first:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

But, everywhere I look, including a dump of variables, there's no comments. What have I missed? I know comments.php is being called.

Here are more details:

I'm not using themes, I have this in the index:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
```

also in the index I have this:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
```

so the work is being done over in content.php, not single or page...

Over in content.php I have this:

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
...
    <h3 id="comments-title"><?php
        printf(
            _n( 'One Response to %2$s', '%1$s Responses to %2$s', get_comments_number(), 'twentytwelve' ),
            number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ),
            '<em>' . get_the_title() . '</em>' 
        );
    ?></h3>
```

That always prints 0.

My loose understanding is that `comments_template()` loads comments.php,  which it does. That seems to be little different than what single.php did. comments.php is stock, but there seems to me to be some initialization missing because although I get the form, it finds no comments.

I was trying to simplify what I needed to do as the blog is simple but the look is complex and fiddly and needs a separate look for mobile which is in a mobile subdomain. I've gotten all this working, except the comments.

[URL](http://www.guidedimagerydownloads.com/blog/chasing-golden-carrot/) for a post that has comments:

Comment: Did you make changes directly to the twenty twelve theme?

Comment: I would start with saving away your changes and returning to square one (original unmodified theme). There is too little information here so far to make a good guess what could poof comments in your case.

Comment: comments templates don't get shown in indices and archives. the comments template is called from single.php.

Comment: I'm not using themes, per se. See revised post which has code flow in it.